# Efficient way to upload files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a aspx webpage where there's an option to upload multiple files.These files have to be stored in the database in BLOB format.
What will be the most efficient manner to store these files? There's no constraint on the size  or number of file to be uploaded. 
Should I upload the files one by one whenever the user clicks the file upload button or
upload them once simultaneously when the whole form gets submitted on save button. Please keep in mind, this is to used by multiple users about ~1000 at a time

Comment: you are uploading 1000's images at a time and storing the blobs in SQL Server? Are you sure that's a good idea? The database is going to get pretty big, very fast

Comment: First, i have already implemented one by one uploading.

Comment: Second, I have to use MSSQL Server only. No other choice. And yes, the table is going to be very large and is going to fill fast. This i'm taking as a scenario only when users will be very large. "One by one or simultaneous uploading" which one is better

Answer (score 1):

Considering that it is a BLOB data, I would consider to use some No-SQL database ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)), where you save just "document" with data, so it's easier to manage in these kind of situations. But you will need more disk space in this case.

What about upload: I would go one after one, as in case if connection drops, at least some of the files are delivered.

On the server side, would look on [Redis](http://redis.io/) like in memory cache that always ready to accept user "session" (a sequence of declared quantity of files), and one time all of them delivered, or connection failure the content of that session is saved on the disk.

Just general overview what can be done to give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. In this proj, we have to use MSSQL only, plus I have implemented the one by one uploading case. Is it better to save these files one by one directly to the main table or should i first save them to a temporary table, then copy them to the main table and lastly delete these entries from the temporary one. I am currently doing the second way, so as to reduce the number of hits to the main table by multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

set file upload control multiple attribute to 'multiple' and in the code behind get request user submitted files, then loop through their memory stream and store them in your db as byte arrays

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitations of your scenario (where the images must be stored in (I assume) a single SQL Database) I would look into uploading the images one by one, and I would investigate if the [SQL Server Transient Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28PandP.50%29.aspx) with the Exponential back-off strategy could help to try and handle the 'queued' uploads.

Without more details I can't really say.

Comment: The TFH block looks like it's for SQL Azure but I am pretty sure the retry logic works with any modern SQL Server. I use it with SQL Azure all the time, it's great.